# c_str() vs std::string - what's the real difference in this piece of small code?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, std, string-comparison

Why does the code below print "NO"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    const std::string abc = "hello";

    if (abc.c_str() == "hello")
    {
        cout << "\nYES";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "NO";
    }
}
```

The `.c_str()` returns `const char*` whereas `"hello"` should be interpreted as either `const char*` or `std::string`, both are valid. But why doesn't it print "YES". `strcmp()` does print "YES", when used instead. But my question is on the code above, is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Why do you think it should say "yes"? Do you understand what's being compared here?

Comment: `abc.c_str() == "hello"` compares pointers. The constant string `"hello"` does not reside at the same address as the heap-allocated `abc.c_str()`, therefore NO, it isn't a compiler bug.

Comment: Yes, I misinterpreted this. I get it that its comparing the buffer pointer with the literal and both of them at this point are not pointing to the same memory location. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "hello" should be interpreted as either const char* or std::string both are valid.

No. `"hello"`  is never interpreted as `std::string`. It has the type `const char[6]`, which in this case is converted to `const char*`. This conversion for arrays is called decaying.

> But why doesn't it print YES.

When you compare two pointers, you compare whether they point to the same object. The pointers that you use compare unequal because the string literal, and the buffer of the `std::string` are not the same object.

> is this a compiler bug?

No. It is a bug in your code.

> so what would you suggest as the right approach with using c_str() and std::string?

The correct way is to compare the content of null terminated character arrays is `std::strcmp`.

Alternatively, you could use the comparison operator with the `std::string` directly, without using the pointer returned by `c_str`. The comparison operator of `std::string` compares with the content of a null terminated string.

Comment: Thanks. Very well ellucidated!

Comment: I still think it was possible in C++03. I'd love an expert to comment.

Comment: @Bathsheba I wouldn't know enough about C++03 to deny the possibility. From what I remember having read, I suppose it would be possible. A case where this programming mistake would go unnoticed until compiler/library upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a compiler bug. `abc.c_str()` is giving you the value of a pointer to the `std::string` data buffer and since C++11, it's impossible for that to be the same address as the address of the literal `"hello"` as that standard forbids copy-on-write semantics for `std::string`. (I believe this was theoretically possible in C++03 and earlier, out of interest.)

If you want to compare a literal with a `std::string`, use

`if (abc == "hello")`

as `std::string` has an appropriate overload for the `==` operator.

Answer (score 2):

`abc.c_str()` is a pointer to the internal buffer of the `abc` object, you're then doing a pointer comparison with the string literal "hello" which returns `false`.

Comment: Thanks, so what would you suggest as the right approach with using c_str() and std::string?

Comment: "hello" can be considered as both a string literal and also as a "const char*", somehow I find your answer is incomplete in this regard. Thanks!

Comment: Right approach for what? To compare c style strings use one of the `strcmp` variants. To compare std::strings use `operator==`

Comment: The string literal "hello" is stored at a different place in memory to the internal buffer of the `abc` object. Comparing pointers to both thus returns false. Does that clear it up?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the wrong way, try:

Instead of:

```
if (abc.c_str() == "hello")
```

use:

```
if (!strcmp(abc.c_str(), "hello"))
```

Comment: Why not just `if(abc == "hello)` ?

Comment: that's possible too :)